# TextView SetText not working in ImageButton onSetClickListener

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView whose id is toptext.  I want to change the text using setText in a onSetClickListener event using the following code

```
 public class testafrnl3 extends Activity {

   private TextView menutitle;
   private ImagView mmovie;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       mmovie = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.movieSelect);
       menutitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toptext);



        mmovie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

             menutitle.setText("Movies2");

           }

    }



}
```

R.id.toptext comes with a value of "Old Movie" from the layout. When I run this code, the textView does not change but once i carry that line of code of the onSetClickListener, it changes. Please does anyone have a solution.

Comment: are you sure this code not working? It works in my eclipse.

Comment: I suggest you add in a Log.v statement to make sure that the onClick method is being called, and that the mmovie and menutitle aren't null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the case of "toptext" correct in the code and the XML? Seems to me it should be topText based on your movieSelect (and standard conventions.)  Looks perfectly fine otherwise.

Comment: incorrect spelling should cause NullPointerException in onClick because no TextView could be found and menutitle will stay null.

Comment: +1 Yep.  You're right.  I just don't see anything else wrong with that code.  Good catch.

Comment: Thanks Everyone,I finally got the problem. The toptext TextView was not directly in the layout file but was included in the layout file and for some reason when I removed the included file and copied the content directly into the layout file, it worked. Thanks